# How can I create a custom 'Block' in Marketing Cloud Content builder for emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, content-builder

I'm looking at the available 'blocks' in the content creator for emails, and discovering they are a little (very) limited.

In other tools of this nature I would be able to create my own block (or whatever term the competitor uses e.g. Module).  Below is an image of a module wireframe.  I could write some HTML/CSS, define variables within that module, and then have the content creator drag this new block onto the email and use as needed by filling in the variables (a sample list would be font size, colour and content for main text, font size, colour, link, and content for button text, image and alt text for background image).

Your thoughts and wisdom are immensely appreciated![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPjko.png)

Comment: Within Content Builder you can create a whole list of custom blocks - Free Form, Text, HTML, Image, A/B test, Dynamic Content, Social Share, Social Follow, Button, Layout, External Content, Image Carousel.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Tom, I know I could create an HTML block to do what I want (as per the image).  What I want is to be able to have the end user (e.g. someone in marketing who is creating an email) be able to say 'I want this image,  this main text, and this button text' but without editing the HTML.. just by filling in variables (a-la Marketo)

Answer (score 3):

Have some faith in your content creators, they can use a template that you created and then change nearly all you said in the template based emails without touching html.

Furthermore you can create many templates of blocks which they just drag into that email and renew the images etc.

Here some screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

If you really want them to use a list that they Specify you'd have to do this:
Your Content Blocks all contain AMPScript Variables that lookup onto a data extension that contains the values that you want to place in those variables.

For example: Email-Data Extension with fields like editorial text, button1 text, etc. But this is highly unflexible if only some of the email templates are changed.

Comment: Johannes, this is a great exposition and I really appreciate the time you've taken here.  

What I'm after is a 'how'.  I admit I am a bit of a n00b to SFMC, and am trying to learn fast.  

Lets say I create a block as per my imgur link as html.  How do I then let the content creator using that block control the various attributes that I listed out in my initial question?

Cheers
Jo

Comment: BTW - I've updated the OP to include the image, rather than just a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

All, after much investigation - what I wanted is available right now.

Apparently however (after dicussions with Salesforce) similar functionality is on the roadmap.